# sort link list lecico grfy (abc...)

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I’m trying to sort by the a b c link list . . how ever when I’m trying to sort 
I’m losing node's . so far I’m see that the line

```
q = top;
```

is the problem. case after one intrusion . `q`  is pointing to `NULL` and I’m losing nose;s that way. how can I return to the head of the list with out corrupting the list 
thanks
here is my code

```
Users* sort_list_Lex(Users* head) {

    Users *p,*q, *top;
    int changed = 1;

    if ((top = (Users *) malloc(sizeof(Users))) == NULL) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory Allocation error.\n");
    }
    top->next = head;
    if (head != NULL && head->next != NULL) {
        while (changed) {
            changed = 0;
            q = top;
            p = top->next;
            while (p->next != NULL) { /* push bigger items down */
                    if (0 < strcmp(p->name, p->next->name)) {
                        q->next = list_switch(p, p->next);
                        changed = 1;
                    }
                q = p;
                if (p->next != NULL)
                    p = p->next;
            }
        }
    }
    p = top->next;
    free(top);
    return p;
}
```

switch func:

```
Users* list_switch(Users *l1, Users *l2) {
    l1->next = l2->next;
    l2->next = l1;
    return l2;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth you will allocate memory for sorting a already built link list?

Comment: There is no need for any dynamic allocation in a bubble-sort of a linked list. There is, however, considerably more pointer swapping required than you may think. The usual way of doing this is to perform adjacent compares/swaps until the end of the list is reached, then **move** the last node to the head of a "sorted" list, then repeat until no swaps are detected (which happens by default with one node left in the source list). When no swaps are detected on *any* iteration, just attach the last node of the source list to the first node in the sorted list and you're done.

Comment: Does `list_switch()` switch the entire struct, or just its data element(s) while leaving its pointers intact?

Comment: No, your recent post of `list_switch()` switches pointers. Just swap the data. As with sorting an indexed array, you don't swap the indices, only the element's data.

Comment: ok, though that's not the problem, the code do the sorting. but i'm losing some node on the way..

Comment: @WeatherVane Exactly the *opposite* is the advantage for linked list sorting. One of the very-few advantages of linked lists is the in-place node relocation capabilities *without* having to move around the underlying data. All that is required to sort linked lists is pointer manipulation. No node data beyond the pointers should need any modification *at all*.

Comment: @WhozCraig He's not moving data, only pointers. So you might as well do that than get tangled up with the issues in your previous comment (assuming his struct does not contain a char name[] array - it's not posted.

Comment: @WeatherVane Correct. He's not, but *you are*. You're telling him he *should*, which is *not* ideal for sorting linked lists. The exact *opposite* is the desired behavior for linked list; adjusting *only* pointers and *not* data.

Comment: Better downvote my answer then and/or supply a better one.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't down-vote answers that solve problems unless they're flat-out wrong, invoke UB, or are so putrid no one sane would do what is proposed. If this question is sourced in academia as I suspect, the very purpose of the exercise is pointer manipulation. And even if it *isn't*, it is *still* optimal to twiddle the pointers rather than move data as a general solution, especially when this eventually goes to where it *should* be for a linked list: merge-sort. So no, I'm not down-voting your answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you, I wasn't aware of that advantage, although I can see it is so if the linked structure contains more bytes of data than pointers.

Comment: @WeatherVane an example that is likely over the top for the OP, but exhibits the properties I describe [**can be seen here**](http://pastebin.com/SkPVx7nV). You have to be *very* comfortable with pointers once you step into double-indirection as the linked snippet describes, which is the primary reason I didn't post it as an answer. it would do no good for me to post code the OP sees as greek (no offense to the Greeks). Doing it *without* double-indirection can indeed become *very* tangled as you noted. Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well yes, but the code would be easier to follow if the list root was passed as a single * pointer and the function returned the new list root pointer. Taking multiple-star pointers to the n'th degree reminds me of the one-line program that no-one but the author comprehends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is unnecessarily complicated. With apologies to @WhozCraig.

```
Users* sort_list_Lex(Users* head) {
    Users *p;
    char *tmp;
    int changed;
    do {
        changed = 0;
        p = head;
        while (p->next) {
            if (0 < strcmp(p->name, p->next->name)) {
                tmp = p->name;
                p->name = p->next>name;
                p->next>name = tmp;
                changed = 1;
            }
            p = p->next;
        }
    } while (changed);
    return head;
}
```

This answer assumes that the char arrays within the linked `struct` are pointers and not a `char name[]` array where the whole data has to be swapped.

Comment: @WhozCraig and to Weather Vane thanks it's work! as i understand when i'm sorting link list i should swap the data.